Switching from guitar to either trumpet, violin or flute - need advice
I have been playing the guitar for 17 years now.
Purely as a fun hobby, always by myself (no interest playing with people).
I still like the guitar, and been playing it almost every day, since I started, back in 2007.
But I don't want to grow fingernails, anymore, and playing with a pick is simply boring. I found myself picking up the guitar less and less, and I don't like it at all, for music has always been an inseparable part of my life (and no, I can't play without nails).
For years, I have been toying with the idea of switching to a more melodic instrument, and the Trumpet, Violin and the flute always came to my mind.
One major issue is: I live with 2 other roommates in an apartment building with thin-paper walls. Since the guitar is a quiet instrument by nature, I never had any playing volume issues, but I read that those 3 are very loud (playing outside is no option)
I would like to hear, from people who have experience with those instruments:

How loud are they for my living quarters? I guess I can get an electric silencer for the trumpet and an electric violin, but would it be actually fun to play with such a setup, as a default?
Those instruments are usually part of an ensemble or an orchestra. How fun would it be to play them, by myself? I don't intend to play anything official pieces, just cover various melodies from my mind.
Taking into account my previous experience with the guitar, is it realistic to learn any of those, by myself?

Answers such as "forget about it and stick to the guitar" are also acceptable. One needs to face reality and accept its limits.
P.S I did teach myself to play the diatonic harmonica, which I do find quiet enough, but very dull and limited in range.
I like the trumpet especially. Its sound always hovered between romantic & classical, and war-like epicness (which shouldn't come as a surprise, considering its origins).

Best option is to rent each one for a month and see what you think. There are new trumpet mutes that make it essentially silent with microphones inside so you can hear on headphones. Flute is naturally quietest of the three. Whether you can learn on your own is hard to say without knowing a lot about you. In my experience, lessons are always worth it as long as the teacher is competent. One more thing: diatonic harmonica is way easier than most other instruments.

Definitely rent and try them out like Todd said, but also be sure to explore violin mutes (there are more styles than that). Not just for brass!

I'm afraid that besides the question about loudness, this is opinion based.

Yes, trumpet, violin or flute will be audible to your neighbours.
The obvious choice for you would be piano - or rather a piano-type keyboard that can be played quietly or through headphones.    And it's one of the few instruments that can be fully satisfying to a lone player.

Unfortunately, this might be the case. I always ignored electric pianos - nothing wrong with them, but they just felt fake to me, compared to the real deal (even the more sophostocated ones, with the weighted keys and overtone immitation). I find myself living too much in the digital world, and playing an acoustic instrument was my retreat into the real world. Having said that, for both the violin and trumpet, I would still need to choose their digital counterparts, if I want to be able to play in a quiet environment.

I have played guitar since I was very young (first had lessons at 10); I took up bass guitar at 14; I switched to fretless bass guitar at 18; I added a baritone guitar at  37.  (I still play all four regularly at 55.)
I came to the violin at 41 when I received one that had belonged to my grandfather and had it serviced to make it playable.
First: Don't worry about violins usually being part of an orchestra. Playing solo and improvising is quite enjoyable.
One challenge for you is that you have only played a fretted instrument.  It will take a lot of practice and listening to get your intonation right. I came to the violin after many years on fretless bass.
The bigger challenge I've had with violin is the short scale when compared to my other string instruments.  It requires a lot of precision in finger position to maintain good intonation. (On the other hand, you may have smaller fingers than me and you won't be bothered by the scale.)

Of the 3, the trumpet would be the easiest to get some tunes out of. On the grounds that notes are readily available, in comparison with violin (intonation problems) and flute (embouchure problems). Unfortunately, it's also the loudest, although it can be quietened down either with practice mutes or an electronic system, adding more expense at least.
You may well miss the propensity to play chords as you can on guitar, but time will tell.
All three could be played in a car, which wouldn't bother anyone then, but you specifically ask about in the apartment. With others having to share your noise, violin goes to the back of the list! Although as you already know, practice violins which are very quiet, would jockey them up to a higher position.
The problem is, they're all very different in the sound produced, how it's produced, and just about everything else. Do you find yourself being drawn towards music produced on one of these, more than the others? Price wise, they're all going to be in the same ball park. As will accessibility for setting up to practise.
Another consideration, which I went with, was a bass guitar. After all, you don't need long nails, and you already have some knowledge as the lower 4 strings of a guitar are tuned the same - EADG.

I like the bass, it is one big guitar, after all. But I always saw it as a supporting role in a band - great instrument to make a career as a session musician, but not sure as for being a solo instrument, especially for melodies.

@mRiddle Listen to some Victor Wooten! or better yet, David Friesen.

@AndyBonner - jaco pastorius  wasn't half bad too...

You’re not aware of the intonation challenges of flute and trumpet? They’re real and can’t be solved by merely moving a finger. Also playing violin in a car? That’s one huge car! Not in my compact.

@ToddWilcox - I did say in comparison. it's much easier to play notes 'in tune' on trumpet than on violin. And we don't all drive little cars.

I totally disagree about which is easier to play notes in tune on. IMHO the violin is the easiest of the three to intonate because all you have to do is move your finger. With the other two there’s so many aspects of breath and embouchure and the valve 3 slide on trumpet and head joint angle on flute, etc, etc.

@ToddWilcox - misunderstanding here. By intonate, I meant play in tune. Once each is tuned in its own right, I still think violin is hardest to hit notes that are in tune.

No misunderstanding. By intonate, I mean play in tune also. I think flute is the hardest of the three to hit notes that are in tune.
